# Triggering HomeKit scene from the command line on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, automation, homekit

For workflow automation purposes, I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger a preconfigured HomeKit scene on macOS Mojave using the command line.

I'm happy with any solution, including using AppleScript to control the Home app, as long as it may be invoked programmatically from the command line or from other software of my own creation running on the same Mac.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like it is possible yet. The only useful options seems to be using a mix of:
Type to Siri,
SiriKit,
Automator or sending a signal to iOS and dealing with it there (either by using IFTTT or your own app)

This GitHub issue has some useful info
https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/issues/2017